# TYPO3 Flexform: Enable show/hide for array elements?

Tags: templates, backend, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-tca

I have created a custom content element in TYPO3 6.2 LTS using FlexForms. The backend user can add tiles with an image, text etc. In the form this is realized in an array. TYPO3 already provided automatically two items for "delete" and "sort/move" for each element (I wish I could add an image but my SO reputation is too low). Is there an easy way to also add the little lamp for "show/hide" in this case?

My Flexform looks like this (abbreviated):

```html
<type>array</type>
<el>                                    
  <title>
    <TCEforms>
      <label>Headline</label>
      <config>
        <type>input</type>
        <size>10</size>
      </config>
    </TCEforms>
  </title>
  <description>
    <TCEforms>
      <label>Description</label>
      <config>
        <type>input</type>
        <size>30</size>
      </config>
    </TCEforms>
  </description>
  ...
</el>
```

Comment: Here you have some reputation from me, add the image, cause I've no idea what are you asking about ;)

Comment: Thank you! I need 10 reputation to upload, so I still can't. I will try posting a link to a screenshot:
It's the result of the form above, the elements have each a delete and move icon. I would like add a "show/hide" icon.http://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t31.0-8/10987326_10205120050754550_3749880763733079976_o.jpg

Comment: Please try to take a look into the `TCA` of the media field. However an enable/disable button does not make sense unless you have a field for enable/disable too. Therefore what should happen if you click this button?

Answer (score 0):

for me, it is no possible.

Your can see here this feature request and the reject from the typo3 team : [feature request](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75196)
As recommended, add a hide check box in your slide element